# Left hand Fingering for G Root Position Dominant 7th Chord?

Tags: piano, practice, fingering

I notice that a lot of people recommend playing a G root position dominant 7th chord in the left hand with the **fingers** **5, 3, 2, 1**. But to me, 5, ***4***, 2, 1 is more comfortable.

Is it considered "*bad*" *practice* to play root position dominant 7th chords this way? Is there a *reason* the fingerings **5, 3, 2, 1** seem to be played *more* often than **5, 4, 2, 1**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One source to refer to is **Cooke**, Mastering the Scales and Arpeggios:

- http://hz.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/d/d3/IMSLP69769-PMLP140424-Cooke-Mastering_the_Scales_and_Arpeggios.pdf

Cooke uses the fingering 5-4-2-1 for a root position dominant seventh chord in the left hand.

[image]

One reason to use 4 instead of 3 on the third of the chord (B natural for G7 in C major)  is it leaves the third finger free to "C" for common chord changes like `G7` to `C`.

Another resource for scales and arpeggios: **Knott**, Scale and Arpeggio Manual.

- https://imslp.org/wiki/Scale_and_Arpeggio_Manual_(Knott%2C_Thomas_B.)

...Part II has the chord materials. Knott seems to use the third finger as standard, however that part starts with a discussion about how to choose between the 4th and 3rd fingers in the left hand. Essentially, choose the finger physically closest to the piano key to play.

A long time ago a professional pianist recommended to me: **Cortot**, Rational Principles of Piano Technique.

- https://imslp.org/wiki/Rational_Principles_of_Piano_Technique_(Cortot%2C_Alfred)

That edition is in Italian, I can't find an English version online. At any rate, page 86 has this figure:

[image]

...although the clef is treble I believe the finger numbering above the staff are right hand and those below are left hand.

Answer (score 1):

Those are probably the two most viable options. I suppose you are playing in root position, pinky on G. The following chord, 9 times out of 8, will be C in some form, and if one wants to play a second inversion of it, it's easier to keep pinky on that G, and then with 5 3 2 1, there's two fingers to lift to play C and E, whereas with 5 4 2 1, there's a 5 3 1 option for the C triad. But, really, the matter is fairly insignificant, and will hinge more on each individual's hand, and fingering disposition.